# admin sales order total shipment empty

Tags: adminhtml, template, programming

I recently have the problem that the yellow block with the total order on the bottom right of the sale order info page stays empty.
I looked into the files and found out that in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml` the following lines should display the content

```
<div class="entry-edit-head"><h4><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Totals') ?></h4></div>
<div class="order-totals"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?></div>
```

The divs are shown, but the second one is empty, so `$this->getChildHtml('order_totals')` doesn't do anything. In the other `*.phtml` files everything seems ok, but in the layout sales.xml file i find things like this:

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
    <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_tax" name="tax" template="sales/order/totals/tax.phtml" />
    <!--<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="footer" template="sales/order/totals/footer.phtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="grand" template="sales/order/totals/grand.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="paid" template="sales/order/totals/paid.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="refunded" template="sales/order/totals/refunded.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="due" template="sales/order/totals/due.phtml" />
        </block>
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="sales.order.view.totals.main" as="main" template="sales/order/totals/main.phtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_subtotal" name="subtotal" template="sales/order/totals/subtotal.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_tax" name="tax" template="sales/order/totals/tax.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="shipping" template="sales/order/totals/shipping.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="discount" template="sales/order/totals/discount.phtml" />
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="giftcert" template="sales/order/totals/item.phtml">
            <action method="setSourceField"><value>giftcert_amount</value></action>
            <action method="setLabel"><value>Gift Certificate</value></action>
        </block>
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="adjustment_positive" template="sales/order/totals/item.phtml">
            <action method="setSourceField"><value>adjustment_positive</value></action>
            <action method="setLabel"><value>Adjustment Refund</value></action>
        </block>
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="adjustment_negative" template="sales/order/totals/item.phtml">
            <action method="setSourceField"><value>adjustment_negative</value></action>
            <action method="setLabel"><value>Adjustment Fee</value></action>
        </block>
    </block>-->
</block>
```

So all the item files are commented out, but the overview should work, i think. Still I uncommented it but it doesn't make any difference.

What do I have to do that the order totals are shown?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check wether there is a child block with the name `order_totals`.
2. If there is not, check wether your XML is loaded (break the XML, then a `SimpleXMLException` should be thrown)
3. Check whether you template is loaded (just put a `echo '222'` in the first line)

And as always: Check system.log and exception.log missing templates are shown there if you are in developer mode.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'child block' ? 
The XML is loaded
The `info.phtml` is loaded, but not the `totals.phtml`, which should be loaded by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>`

Comment: the method getChildHtml() makes all the rendering and stuff, the question is: is there a block. you can check with `echo get_class($this->getChild('order_totals'));`

Comment: This doesn't output anything. Is there a method to get the name of the current block?

Comment: `$this->getNameInLayout()`, try a `var_dump()` instead. If the block is not found `false` is returned. And if you echo false, there is no output - but this you know for sure :)

Comment: yup you're right, it returns false. I checked getNameInLayout() and it returns `order_tab_info`. In the sales.xml file (I assume this is the file where the blocks are defined for that section) I find a block with name `order_tab_info` and it has a child named `order_totals`, see my original post for that block code.

Comment: block not found, template not found,l have a look into the exception.log and system.log (and check whether logging is on)

Comment: Problem found? Write down your solution or mark my answer as solution :-)